# Upvote First for StackOverflow - Chrome extension that sorts answers by your votes

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, answers

[image: banner]

## Upvote First for Stack Overflow

Chrome extension that sorts Stack Overflow answers by your upvotes.

- Available on [Chrome Extension store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/upvote-first-for-stackove/jafbgebfjkfejghbdeohaadmfghkmjlo)
- 100% free and [open source](https://github.com/lets-hack-stuff/stackoverflow-upvote-first/)
- works on all Stack Exchange sites

## <kbd>[Install Upvote First for Stack Overflow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/upvote-first-for-stackove/jafbgebfjkfejghbdeohaadmfghkmjlo)</kbd>

---

### Why did I do this?

I find myself **revisiting Stack Overflow questions** I've already read.

When there are **multiple answers** (and approaches to solve something), I upvote **my chosen answer**

Some time later, I find myself **re-visiting that question**.
Since I want to spare that research I already did in the past, I try to **find the upvoted answers made by my user** (to get an acknowledge by myself).

#### Scrolling down?

What bothers me in this process is the fact that answers **aren't always at the top** and I have to scroll down to the bottom to see them.

**That sucks.** Therefore I made this chrome extension that **re-sorts the answers** by your votes. For instance, if you upvoted an answer and revisited that question later, it will appear first in the answers list.

#### Background

I [suggested this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278810/295552) on Meta Stack Exchange. **However**, it seems this might not got the attention of their Product Manager.

Since I see Stack Overflow as an important tool in my daily routine, I implemented this chrome extension as a weekend project mainly to help myself and other developers be more productive :+1:.

---

#### Demo

[image: video tutorial]

- click to watch the [demo on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHF-wiVDUSM)

---

#### Icon

[image]

Comment: I like the idea and it UI but I personally think the extension would make more sense as a pageAction rather than a browserAction.  Either way, nicely done.

Comment: I've built a similar extension which does similar stuff - I'm planning to add this into it later - https://stackapps.com/q/9515/96492