# Stack Me First - Highlight & List all the linked answers, comments & linked questions related to the current user

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, firefox

## Stack Me First [image: Picture of Stack Me first logo]

A browser extension to Highlight, Sort & display a list of all questions, comments or links answered and upvoted by the current user.

[image: Stack Me First v5 Demo]

### About

This Plugin has 3 components to it

#### 1. Sidebar

#### 2. Popup:

Sidebar and popup contain mostly the same information.

- Sidebar is always accessible whereas
- Popup needs to be manually clicked and it automatically closes when you click-away.

**Features:**

- The User Preferences section allows the user to choose preferences to disable extracting information if required
- The Login/Logout buttons allow the user to log in which enables enhanced features to identify hidden information (like hidden comments or linked questions you upvoted/favorited) (**yet to be deployed**)

Based on the current question and the logged-in user, the popup shows a list of

- All the answers - posted by the logged-in user (**login is optional**)
- All the comments - posted by the logged-in user (**login is optional**)
- All the linked questions - upvoted/favorited by the logged-in user (**yet to be deployed, mandatory login**)

[Stack Me First - Popup Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSO43.png)

#### 3. Highlights content in the current question in the DOM

Highlights the Questions, comments & Linked Questions upvoted by the logged-in user with a green/orange border

[Stack Me First - Question Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXFXa.png)

---

### License

[GNU GPL version 3](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/StackMeFirst/blob/main/LICENSE)

### Download

- [GitHub SourceCode](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/StackMeFirst)
- [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-me-first/pmjhehdfjfahnlgdblnhhfcimegodmnj)
- [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-me-first/)
- [Microsoft Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/stack-me-first/andilefigneejkadafmdfcmjdnabfbhi)

#### Platform

- [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome)
- [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox)
- [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)

### Contact

Created by [Gangula](https://stackapps.com/users/96492/gangula)

### Known Bugs:

- [Favorites not being highlighted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385726/381523)
- [Linked questions not being highlighted for few questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383720/381523)